# remove elements javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to remove a row. But i can't figure it out really.
First of all I've got a button that'll add a new row, that works.
But I want to give the user the possibility to remove the just added row.
The row has an 'div' inside what acts as an deletebutton. But the deletebutton doesn't work?

I'm I missing something?

Greet,

Juki

```
function addrow() {
$("#container").append("<div id=\"row_added\"><div class=\"deletebutton\" id=\"delbuttonnumber\"></div><div id=\"addedcolor\" class=\"colorcube\"></div></div>");
}

// deleterow the row
$(".deletebutton").click(function() {
    rowclrid = "#" + $(this).parent().attr("id");
    $(rowclrid).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need to do is use the [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method. This will add the events for any new item that is added to the DOM, not just the ones that exist when you set the `click` handler.

```
// deleterow the row
$(".deletebutton").live('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

You also don't need to get the row by getting the ID - it's simpler in the way above.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you have assigned the click handler before adding the new content, so the handler is not attached to this particular element.  You can use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to listen for events on all elements below a particular parent element, whether or not they already exist:

```
$('#container').delegate('.deletebutton', 'click', function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

This listens for all click events that happen inside the element `#container` using a feature of the DOM called [event bubbling](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-bubbling), then checks to see if they happened on a `.deletebutton` element, and, if so, calls the handler.

Note also the simplified code inside the handler.